# How to improve the performance of odoo response time

Tags: python, azure, odoo

I am using odoo community version in microsoft azure 1 core ubuntu 14.04 VM. It's performance is very bad. A single page takes 12 to 15 sec to load a page.

I am running odoo with odoo.py

Has there any way hat I can improve performance?

Comment: Your description for Azure Ubuntu VM you used is not clear. Besides only 1 CPU core, I don't know any information for Memory RAM, etc. Please refer to [Azure offical pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/) to improve your VM information, such as what category of Linux VM like A0/A1.

Comment: Meanwhile, I suggest that you can try to check the minimun hardware requirement for odoo & postgresql to select a suitable VM instance, please refer to https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/what-is-the-minimum-server-hardware-requirment-to-run-open-erp-68748 & https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/m3k75ewlwa.fsf@wolfe.cbbrowne.com.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I don't know whether you were running database like postgres for odoo on the same VM. If so, I suggest that you should upgrade your VM tier which has more CPU core & Memory RAM to satisfy the minimum hardware requirement of odoo & database to improve the performance.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I currently am running Odoo 10 Community Edition on a Standard D2_v2 VM (2Core, 7Gigs of memory). I have a multi-database (more than 10) Odoo running with 5 workers. Another Odoo instance doing backups of my databases on a Blob Storage. On the same server I host a Django Project for the administration of those instances.

I set it up using nginx (Odoo) and uWSGI (Django). You should give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Try to configure it with Apache2 web server using wsgi. That could really improve response time.